# XAMPP HTDOCS, html elements getting commands from wrong (non present ) javascripts scripts in root folder

Tags: javascript, html, xampp

i was working on an html/php program on my local server using XAMPP,i realised that html elements were getting javascript commands from  wrong scripts located in  other subfolders folders ,
however there were similar scripts with different name but same javascript code (used as backup)available in other folders .  in my head tag i tripple checked my directory for the script src to make sure that i was olny calling the script from one specific foler
i even tried deleting all jacascript scripts from my head tag and root folder but elements could still workd despite not having functions or any Javascript commds to read from, how is that possible ?
can someone please help me understand why my html elements are reading from wrong javascript source??

```
<body>
    <!--player script-->
    <script>
        player();
    </script>
    <audio class="w3-bottom" src="" controls id="player">
        Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
    </audio>


        <ul id="playlist">
            <li class="current-song song" id="song">
                <a href="alpha.mp3" id="song"> </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="bobby.mp3" id="song">bobby</a> </li>
            <li><a href="track.mp3" id="song">track</a></li>
            <li><a href="bobby.mp3" id="song">bobby</a> </li>
            <li><a href="track.mp3" id="song">track</a></li>
        </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Please include code sample. That will be easier to spot the problem.

Comment: sorry . i  have updated the quesion

Answer (score 0):

i fugured it out ,
i had to uncomment the code below from httpd.conf  then  clear browsing history also restart apache. my code works now !

EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off